# using takeWhile AND filters with list comprehension issue

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension, ghci

I am confused why GHCI is calculating this list infinitely:

```
takeWhile (>0) [x^2 | x <- [100, 99..], odd x]
```

This list, however, stops and is calculated as expected:

```
takeWhile (>0) [x | x <- [100, 99..], odd x]
```

What am I missing here? Why is it that squaring the input causes takeWhile(>0) to have no effect?

Also, this list ends as expected...why does this terminate but not the other?

```
takeWhile (<1000) [x^2 | x <- [1..], odd x]
```

Also, if I remove the odd x filter from the first list, it terminates properly:

```
takeWhile (>0) [x^2 | x <- [100, 99..]]
```

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x^2` always `>0` for `x /= 0`.

You could change list to this:

```
[x^2 | x <- [100, 99..], odd x, x > 0]
```

Comment: This will never finish. After x has reached 0 it will continue trying lower numbers forever, but never print anything because none of them are <0. You should instead change it to `[x^2 | x <- takeWhile (>0) [100,99..], odd x]`, although it is a bit more cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

Because `x^2 >= 0` is always true. So you do actually have an infinite list, example

```
-1 * -1 = 1 > 0
```

This is just math.

So there's only one case where `x^2 > 0` fails, when `x = 0`. When you have the `odd x` condition in there `0` is never considered so the list never terminates. When you remove it, it stops when `x=0`.

Finally, the third list trivially terminates since `100 * 100 > 1000`.

Comment: DOH! I feel like an idiot, for some reason I assumed that takeWhile (>0) was applied to x <- [100, 99..] BEFORE x^2...I'm not sure why I assumed that. Thanks for pointing out the obvious :D

Comment: @user2293246 No worries :) Don't worry, I've made dumber mistakes

Comment: @user2293246: This may be a good example of where it's much clearer to use list combinators rather than comprehension notation.  Note the difference between `takeWhile (>0) . map (^2) . filter odd` and `map (^2) . takeWhile (>0) . filter odd`.